# end a setTimeout function before its set time

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a jquery function that when clicked produces a set timeout on making a div visible.

however, if another option is selected during the settimeout length, i would like to know how to destroy this function and stoop anything else in it happening.

my current code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('li#contact').click(function () {
        $('ul.image_display').css('display', 'none');
        $('ul.projects').fadeOut().hide();
        $('li#cv').removeClass('cur');
        $('li#projects').removeClass('cur');
        $('li#contact').addClass('cur');
        $('ul.contact').fadeIn(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('ul.contact').fadeOut('slow');
            }, 8000);
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('li#contact').removeClass('cur');
            $('li#cv').addClass('cur');
            $('ul.projects').fadeIn('slow');
            $('ul.image_display').css('display', 'block');
        }, 8625);

    });

});
```

a bit cumbersome but works until this is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#projects').click(function () {
        $('li#cv').removeClass('cur');
        $('ul.contact').fadeOut().hide();
        $('#contact').removeClass('cur');
        $('ul.projects').fadeIn('slow');
        $('#projects').addClass('cur');
        $('ul.image_display').css('display', 'block');
    });

});
```

if the second is clicked just after the first than class 'cur' still comes up on li#cv after the set time.

Comment: i know the code sucks ass but I'm still new to this whole jquery malarkey!

Comment: by the way setTimeout is a javascript function nothing to do with jQuery (regarding your title) :)

Comment: that maybe why I couldn't find anything in the jquery docs about it! Cheers dude

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) function returns an identifier to that timeout. You can then cancel that timeout with the [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) function. So you can do something like this (fill in the blanks with your code):

```
var timer;
$(function() {
    $(...).click(function() {
        ...
        timer = setTimeout(...);
        ...
    });

    $(...).click(function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });
});
```

It's not particularly super clean to keep a global variable for this, however. You could store the timer in the [`data`](http://docs.jquery.com/Data) attribute of whatever element makes the most sense for your situation. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(...).click(function() {
        ...
        var timer = setTimeout(...);
        $(someelement).data('activetimer', timer);
        ...
    });

    $(...).click(function() {
        var timer = $(someelement).data('activetimer');
        if(timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $(someelement).removeData('activetimer');
        }
    });
});
```

It doesn't really *look* cleaner, but it's an alternative way to store the timer...

Comment: sorry, could you elaborate slightly for me? 

Where would this go in the code?

Comment: When you set the timeout, save the return value of the setTimeout to a variable -- in the example, "timer". When you want to end it, you can call clearTimeout() on "timer", which will just cancel the impending event. It won't make the Timeout event happen ahead of time, it will just make it never happen, so you will have to also program a way for the code that went in to the Timeout to be executed otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `clearTimeout()` to do that.  You'll need to keep the return value from `setTimeout()` in a variable to pass to `clearTimeout()`.